# Sharing Customer login details between two different magento sites (abc.com and xyz.com)

Tags: magento-1.9

I am very new to magento and i have two sites abc.com , xyz.com. Now i want the user to sign up in one site (abc.com) and the same credentials should work on xyz.com

Both of them on magento and have their individual inventory and admin panel

Thanks in advance

Comment: this is closed by Keyul shah stating that it is too broad... Seriously???? this could have been fairly a simple one....